# Could Someone point me to a good summary of haskell code conventions

Tags: haskell, coding-style

Particularly about indentation and under_score/camelCase/longalllowercasewords.

Comment: As I know camelCase - is one which is used. First letter big for types and data constructors. underscore at the end usualy means loosing some information (like `mapM_`). About indention - it syntax dependant, and when there is some freedom, I usually try to make it like "looks nice".

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983047/good-haskell-coding-standards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ian's document is good but a bit thin.  I've [already answered a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983047/good-haskell-coding-standards/1983310#1983310) but I added something about the case of words.

Comment: See also the style section of haskell.org: http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Category:Style

Answer (score 10):

[Good Haskell Style](http://urchin.earth.li/~ian/style/haskell.html), by Dr. Ian Lynagh of Well-Typed.

Answer (score 2):

There's also http://github.com/tibbe/haskell-style-guide/blob/master/haskell-style.md, which comes with an accompanying haskell-style.el file for use with haskell-mode in Emacs.